# How do I change the appearance of tab characters in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, tabs, ide, formatting, indentation

Personally I find the tab display character in IntelliJ IDEA noisy.

[image: Tabs in Intellij]

I would prefer that tabs would be displayed as in Eclipse:

[image]

Is it possible to change the display of tabs in IntelliJ?

Comment: I don't think you can. But one thing I've done is adjust the color of the white space characters to be closer to the background: similar enough that they blend in when I'm looking at other things, but different enough that it's not too hard to see when looking right at them.

Comment: I created a ticket in their issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142429

Comment: I've voted for the issue created by @GunnarHillert .

Comment: Amazing 3 years, 9 months ago and still an open issue.

Comment: They've just changed it to be more like Eclipse in 2019.3 but it doesn't seem to be configurable. (Looks way uglier now too - https://xkcd.com/1172/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appearance of tab characters in the IntelliJ IDEA editor is currently [hard-coded](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/openapi/editor/impl/ArrowPainter.java).

Comment: Somehow I feared that answer :-)